# How to print color as RGB

Tags: java, colors, rgb

How can I print a color in RGB format? I am using `Robot(java.awt)` to get the color of a random pixel on the screen and I want to print it as RGB. So if the pixel is completely red, the output should be

```
rgb(255, 0, 0)
```

Is there something I can do? Should I get the individual red green and blue values(and how can I do that)? Here's what I got so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    Robot r = null;
    int screenHeight = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();
    int screenWidth = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();

    try {
        r = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Color pixelColor = r.getPixelColor(rand.nextInt(screenHeight), rand.nextInt(screenWidth));
    System.out.println(pixelColor);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

But it outputs this(random example):

```
java.awt.Color[r=222,g=228,b=239]
```

---

EDIT: I also tried using `getRGB()` but it still does not work.

```
    //...
    Color pixelColor = r.getPixelColor(rand.nextInt(screenHeight), rand.nextInt(screenWidth));
    System.out.println(pixelColor.getRGB());
    //...
```

But it outputs(random example):

```
-723724
```

What do these numbers mean?

Comment: You can get the color for red with `pixelColor.r`, just replace r with g or b for green and blue

Comment: *"What do these numbers mean?"* that means it's a integer packed value (RGB(A)) values packed into a single `int` - You could get the individual color components (ie `getRed`, `getGreen`, `getBlue`) which will give you indiviudal components of the color, which is basically what your second output is saying

Comment: @KeithM I just tried, and it did not work for me. I also tried `pixelColor.getRGB().r` with no luck

Comment: @KeithM I'm kind of curious about what API you think is been used, based on the return value of `Robot#getPixelColor`

Comment: @MadProgrammer my mistake, I was thinking of other Java libraries I've used where they provided a color class that was just `color.r/g/b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start by having a look at a really simple test

```
Color color = Color.RED;
System.out.println(color);
System.out.println(color.getRGB());
System.out.println(color.getRed() + ", " + color.getGreen() + ", " + color.getBlue());
```

Which outputs

```
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
-65536
255, 0, 0
```

The first is the `Color` objects `toString` method, which is providing you information about the class and the properties, as you can see, the `red` property is `255`

The second is a integer packed value (the red, green and blue (and alpha) properties all packed into a single `int` value)

The last is, obviously, each individual property of the color, which would seem to be what you're actually after.

What I think you should do, is go have a read of the [JavaDocs on the `Color` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) so you better understand what information it provides, rather then randomly taking stabs at what you think it should provide

Comment: Very nice and informative answer to a crap question. +1

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's a shame we don't have a close option for "read the documentation" :P

Comment: We do though: Off topic because: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: "I'm too lazy to read the docs" counts as a request for an offsite resource in my book, even if OP does not realize that that is what they are asking sometimes.